# failsafe-failure after installing AMD fglrx driver in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, graphics, xorg, intel, fglrx

After trying every option I can think of (and from the Web), I am forcefully have to ask here :)

So first of all my gear:

```
A Dell e6540 laptop CPU Intel Haswell 4800MQ (igpu 4600), 
GPU AMD 8790m
```

`lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
```

`lshw` (current working drivers):

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED      
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c40000-f7c5ffff

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f5800000-f5bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`uname`:

```
Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

OS issue:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1
- Running in dual-boot (The other one is Windows 8.1).
- Using TLP (Power Management)

As you can see I installed Intel video drivers for 4600 igpu, and I am using the open-source driver for AMD hd8790m.

After installing any version of fglrx driver (all Ubuntu's repo one, from amd webstie,sgfxi one),I get (after plymouth) the 'This system is running in low graphic mode' and afterwards it (also) fails and I get only tty console (tty 7 is blank); I checked `xorg.conf` and it has amd section (`amdconfig --initial`).

And I tried the grub thingy from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218045&p=13056714#post13056714).

Here some logs:

`x-0.log`:

```
...
...
...    
Loading extension GLX
    (EE) 
    (EE) Backtrace:
    (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7fed404a5d28]
    (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x1aca19) [0x7fed404a9a19]
    (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fed3f3fa000+0x10340) [0x7fed3f40a340]
    (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fed3a8d0000+0x67e80) [0x7fed3a937e80]
    (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (xf86DeleteScreen+0x5d) [0x7fed4039ad4d]
    (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (xf86BusConfig+0x1c6) [0x7fed40386556]
    (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x993) [0x7fed403942b3]
    (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x596bb) [0x7fed403566bb]
    (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fed3de39ec5]
    (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x44dde) [0x7fed40341dde]
    (EE) 
    (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x870d0
    (EE) 
    Fatal server error:
    (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
    (EE) 
    (EE) 
    Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
     for help. 
    (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
    (EE) 
    (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

x-0.log.old:

```
Loading extension GLX
Loading extension GLESX
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f4a33af7d28]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f4a3394f000+0x1aca19) [0x7f4a33afba19]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f4a32a4c000+0x10340) [0x7f4a32a5c340]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f4a2df22000+0x15660) [0x7f4a2df37660]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f4a2df22000+0x10dfe9) [0x7f4a2e02ffe9]
(EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f4a2df22000+0x10e545) [0x7f4a2e030545]
(EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so (xdl_xs115_atiddxPxScreenInit+0x72) [0x7f4a2ea086a2]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so (xdl_xs115_atiddxScreenInit+0x11f4) [0x7f4a2e9e4e24]
(EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (AddScreen+0x71) [0x7f4a339a4ca1]
(EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x3c8) [0x7f4a339e5ce8]
(EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7f4a3394f000+0x596bb) [0x7f4a339a86bb]
(EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f4a3148bec5]
(EE) 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7f4a3394f000+0x44dde) [0x7f4a33993dde]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x18
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
[     6.970] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[     6.971] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     6.971] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     6.971] Current Operating System: Linux  3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
[     6.971] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=f70c2b74-5d96-4aaa-99a0-ec75debe9204 ro acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     6.971] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[     6.971] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     6.971] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[     6.971]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     6.971] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     6.971] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Oct 21 14:27:45 2014
[     6.971] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     6.971] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     6.971] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[     6.971] (**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
[     6.971] (**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
[     6.971] (**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
[     6.971] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     6.971] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     6.971] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     6.971] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     6.971] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     6.971]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.971] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     6.971] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     6.971] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     6.971] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     6.971] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     6.971] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fed40729d40
[     6.971] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     6.971]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     6.971]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[     6.971]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[     6.971]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     6.972] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     6.973] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1028:05be rev 6, Mem @ 0xf5800000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[     6.973] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 1002:6606:1028:05be rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf7c00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension Present
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[     6.973] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[     6.973] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     6.973] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[     6.973] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     6.975] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     6.980] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[     6.980]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.980] Loading extension GLX
[     6.980] (II) LoadModule: "fgl.renamed.libglx"
[     6.981] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fgl.renamed.libglx
[     6.981] (II) UnloadModule: "fgl.renamed.libglx"
[     6.981] (II) Unloading fgl.renamed.libglx
[     6.981] (EE) Failed to load module "fgl.renamed.libglx" (module does not exist, 0)
[     6.981] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[     6.981] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[     6.994] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[     6.994]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.30.4
[     6.994]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     6.994] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[     6.994] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[     6.994] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[     7.034] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[     7.034]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.30.4
[     7.034] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:14.30.4
[     7.034] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-14.301.1001              
[     7.034] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Sep 15 2014 18:11:36
[     7.034] (++) using VT number 7

[     7.035] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[     7.043] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[     7.044] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 248
[     7.044] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 248
[     7.044] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[     7.044] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[     7.044] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     9.160] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 9
[     9.160] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[     9.197] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x6606) found
[     9.197] (II) fglrx: intel VGA device detected, load intel driver.
[     9.197] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     9.197] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     9.199] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     9.199]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.911
[     9.199]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     9.199]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     9.200] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7fed422d7670
[     9.201] (II) intel(1): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.911-0intel1 (Andrew Lee (李健秋) <andrew.lee@collabora.co.uk>)
[     9.202] (II) intel(1): pEnt->device->identifier=(nil)
[     9.202] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     9.202] (EE) 
[     9.202] (EE) Backtrace:
[     9.202] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7fed404a5d28]
[     9.202] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x1aca19) [0x7fed404a9a19]
[     9.202] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fed3f3fa000+0x10340) [0x7fed3f40a340]
[     9.202] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fed3a8d0000+0x67e80) [0x7fed3a937e80]
[     9.203] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (xf86DeleteScreen+0x5d) [0x7fed4039ad4d]
[     9.203] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (xf86BusConfig+0x1c6) [0x7fed40386556]
[     9.203] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x993) [0x7fed403942b3]
[     9.203] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x596bb) [0x7fed403566bb]
[     9.203] (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fed3de39ec5]
[     9.203] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fed402fd000+0x44dde) [0x7fed40341dde]
[     9.203] (EE) 
[     9.203] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x870d0
[     9.203] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     9.203] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[     9.203] (EE) 
[     9.203] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     9.203] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     9.203] (EE) 
[     9.219] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

`Xorg.failsafe.log`:

[too many chars :S - uploaded to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0i3PeMyC)

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution for this? 
When I use the standard driver from Xorg, do an apt-update / upgrade the system falls back on low grahics mode ...